# How to find out the cause of an "Invalid Free()" error inside valgrind report

Tags: c, memory-management, valgrind

I wrote an xml editor which compiles fine without warning or errors and run without memory leaks. However i keep getting this error `Invalid Free()` when i run valgrind and i can't figure out what's causing it.

I thought that it could be related to running the `free` command on a null or freed pointer but i couldn't point it out? what's causing it and how do i tell from the report?

(here's my full code, sorry it's a bit long)

### xml.h

```
#ifndef _XML_header

#define MAX 10

xmlDoc *doc;
xmlNode *root;
int count;
char *cursor;
struct child
{
    const xmlChar *grandfather;
    const xmlChar *father;
    const xmlChar *name;
    xmlNode *node;
};
struct spouse
{
    const xmlChar *husband;
    const xmlChar *name;
    struct child **children;
    xmlNode *node;
};
struct special
{
    const xmlChar *name;
    const xmlChar *value;
    const xmlChar *details;
    xmlNode *node;
};
struct selectedNode
{
    const xmlChar *name;
    const xmlChar *father;
    const xmlChar *grandfather;
    struct spouse **spouses;
    struct special **specialItems;
    struct spouse *selectedSpouse;
    struct special *selectedSpecialItem;
    xmlNode *node;
};
struct child **cont;
struct selectedNode *selected;
void check(int condition);

#endif
```

---

### xml.c

```
#include <libxml2/libxml/parser.h>
#include <libxml2/libxml/tree.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "xml.h"

xmlNode *getParent(xmlNode *node)
{
    xmlNode *cur = node->parent;
    while (cur != NULL)
    {
        if (cur->type == XML_ELEMENT_NODE && !xmlStrcmp(cur->name, (const xmlChar *) "child"))
            return cur;
        cur = cur->parent;
    }
    return NULL;
}

const xmlChar *getContent(xmlNode *node, const xmlChar *type)
{
    xmlNode *cur;
    for (cur = node->children; cur != NULL; cur = cur->next)
    {
        if (cur->type == XML_ELEMENT_NODE && !xmlStrcmp(cur->name, type))
            return xmlNodeListGetString(doc, cur->xmlChildrenNode, 1);
    }
    return (const xmlChar *) "none";
}

const xmlChar *getName(xmlNode *node)
{
    return getContent(node, (const xmlChar *) "name");
}

const xmlChar *getGender(xmlNode *node)
{
    return getContent(node, (const xmlChar *) "gender");
}

const xmlChar *getBirthdate(xmlNode *node)
{
    return getContent(node, (const xmlChar *) "born");
}

const xmlChar *getDeathdate(xmlNode *node)
{
    return getContent(node, (const xmlChar *) "died");
}

int setContent(xmlNode *node, const xmlChar *nodeName, const xmlChar *content)
{
    xmlNode *cur;
    for (cur = node->children; cur != NULL; cur = cur->next)
    {
        if (cur->type == XML_ELEMENT_NODE && !xmlStrcmp(cur->name, nodeName))
        {
            xmlNodeSetContent(cur, content);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int setName(xmlNode *node, const xmlChar *name)
{
    return setContent(node, (const xmlChar *) "name", name);
}

int setGender(xmlNode *node, const xmlChar *gender)
{
    return setContent(node, (const xmlChar *) "gender", gender);
}

int setBirthdate(xmlNode *node, const xmlChar *born)
{
    return setContent(node, (const xmlChar *) "born", born);
}

int setDeathdate(xmlNode *node, const xmlChar *died)
{
    return setContent(node, (const xmlChar *) "died", died);
}

struct child *getChild(xmlNode *node, const xmlChar *father, const xmlChar *grandfather)
{
    check(!xmlStrcmp(node->name, (const xmlChar *) "child"));
    struct child *temp = calloc(1, sizeof(struct child));
    temp->father = father;
    temp->grandfather = grandfather;
    temp->name = getName(node);
    temp->node = node;
    return temp;
}

struct child **getChildren(xmlNode *node, const xmlChar *father, const xmlChar *grandfather)
{
    check(!xmlStrcmp(node->name, (const xmlChar *) "spouse"));
    xmlNode  *cur;
    int i = 0;
    struct child **childrenCont = NULL;
    for (cur = node->children; cur != NULL; cur = cur->next)
    {
        if (cur->type == XML_ELEMENT_NODE && !xmlStrcmp(cur->name, (const xmlChar *) "children"))
        {
            if (!cur->children) return NULL;
            childrenCont = calloc(1, sizeof(struct child *));
            childrenCont[0] = NULL;
            for (cur = cur->children; cur != NULL; cur = cur->next)
            {
                if (cur->type == XML_ELEMENT_NODE)
                {
                    childrenCont = realloc(childrenCont, (i + 2) * sizeof(struct child *));
                    childrenCont[i] = getChild(cur, father, grandfather);
                    childrenCont[i + 1] = NULL;
                    i++;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return childrenCont;
}

struct spouse *getSpouse(xmlNode *node, const xmlChar *husband, const xmlChar *fatherinlaw)
{
    check(!xmlStrcmp(node->name, (const xmlChar *) "spouse"));
    struct spouse *temp = calloc(1, sizeof(struct spouse));
    temp->name = getName(node);
    temp->children = getChildren(node, husband, fatherinlaw);
    temp->husband = husband;
    temp->node = node;
    return temp;
}


struct spouse **getSpouses(xmlNode *node, const xmlChar *husband, const xmlChar *fatherinlaw)
{
    check(!xmlStrcmp(node->name, (const xmlChar *) "child"));
    xmlNode *cur;
    int i = 0;
    struct spouse **spousesCont = NULL;
    for (cur = node->children; cur != NULL; cur = cur->next)
    {
        if (cur->type == XML_ELEMENT_NODE && !xmlStrcmp(cur->name, (const xmlChar *) "spouses"))
        {
            if (!cur->children) return NULL;
            spousesCont = calloc(1, sizeof(struct spouse *));
            spousesCont[0] = NULL;
            for (cur = cur->children; cur != NULL; cur = cur->next)
            {
                if (cur->type == XML_ELEMENT_NODE)
                {
                    spousesCont = realloc(spousesCont, (i + 2) * sizeof(struct spouse *));
                    spousesCont[i] = getSpouse(cur, husband, fatherinlaw);
                    spousesCont[i + 1] = NULL;
                    i++;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return spousesCont;
}

struct special *getSpecialItem(xmlNode *node)
{
    check(!xmlStrcmp(node->name, (const xmlChar *) "item"));
    struct special *temp = calloc(1, sizeof(struct special));
    xmlNode *cur;
    for (cur = node->children; cur != NULL; cur = cur->next)
    {
        if (cur->type == XML_ELEMENT_NODE)
        {
            if (!xmlStrcmp(cur->name, (const xmlChar *) "name"))
                temp->name = xmlNodeListGetString(doc, cur->xmlChildrenNode, 1);
            else if (!xmlStrcmp(cur->name, (const xmlChar *) "value"))
                temp->value = xmlNodeListGetString(doc, cur->xmlChildrenNode, 1);
            else if (!xmlStrcmp(cur->name, (const xmlChar *) "details"))
                temp->details = xmlNodeListGetString(doc, cur->xmlChildrenNode, 1);
        }
    }
    temp->node = node;
    return temp;
}

struct special **getSpecial(xmlNode *node)
{
    check(!xmlStrcmp(node->name, (const xmlChar *) "child"));
    xmlNode *cur;
    int i = 0;
    struct special **specialCont = calloc(1, sizeof(struct special *));
    for (cur = node->children; cur != NULL; cur = cur->next)
    {
        if (cur->type == XML_ELEMENT_NODE && !xmlStrcmp(cur->name, (const xmlChar *) "special"))
        {
            for (cur = cur->children; cur != NULL; cur = cur->next)
            {
                if (cur->type == XML_ELEMENT_NODE)
                {
                    specialCont = realloc(specialCont, (i + 2) * sizeof(struct special *));
                    specialCont[i] = getSpecialItem(cur);
                    specialCont[i + 1] = NULL;
                    i++;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return specialCont;
}

void addChild(xmlNode *node, const xmlChar *name, const xmlChar *born, const xmlChar *died)
{
    check(xmlStrcmp(node->name, (const xmlChar *) "spouse"));
    xmlNode *cur;
    xmlNode *childrenCont = NULL;
    for (cur = node->children; cur != NULL; cur = cur->next)
    {
        if (cur->type == XML_ELEMENT_NODE && !xmlStrcmp(cur->name, (const xmlChar *) "children"))
            childrenCont = cur;
    }
    if (childrenCont == NULL) childrenCont = xmlNewChild(node, NULL, (const xmlChar *) "children", NULL);
    xmlNewChild(childrenCont, NULL, (const xmlChar *) "name", name);
    xmlNewChild(childrenCont, NULL, (const xmlChar *) "born", born);
    xmlNewChild(childrenCont, NULL, (const xmlChar *) "died", died);
    xmlNewChild(childrenCont, NULL, (const xmlChar *) "spouses", NULL);
    xmlNewChild(childrenCont, NULL, (const xmlChar *) "special", NULL);
}

void addSpouse(xmlNode *node, const xmlChar *name, const xmlChar *born, const xmlChar *died)
{
    check(xmlStrcmp(node->name, (const xmlChar *) "child"));
    xmlNode *cur;
    xmlNode *spousesCont = NULL;
    for (cur = node->children; cur != NULL; cur = cur->next)
    {
        if (cur->type == XML_ELEMENT_NODE && !xmlStrcmp(cur->name, (const xmlChar *) "spouses"))
            spousesCont = cur;
    }
    if (spousesCont == NULL) spousesCont = xmlNewChild(node, NULL, (const xmlChar *) "spouses", NULL);
    xmlNewChild(spousesCont, NULL, (const xmlChar *) "name", name);
    xmlNewChild(spousesCont, NULL, (const xmlChar *) "born", born);
    xmlNewChild(spousesCont, NULL, (const xmlChar *) "died", died);
    xmlNewChild(spousesCont, NULL, (const xmlChar *) "children", NULL);
    xmlNewChild(spousesCont, NULL, (const xmlChar *) "special", NULL);
}

void addSpecial(xmlNode *node, const xmlChar *name, const xmlChar *value, const xmlChar *details)
{
    check(!xmlStrcmp(node->name, (const xmlChar *) "child"));
    xmlNode *cur;
    xmlNode *specialCont = NULL;
    for (cur = node->children; cur != NULL; cur = cur->next)
    {
        if (cur->type == XML_ELEMENT_NODE && !xmlStrcmp(cur->name, (const xmlChar *) "special"))
            specialCont = cur;
    }
    if (specialCont == NULL) specialCont = xmlNewChild(node, NULL, (const xmlChar *) "special", NULL);
    xmlNewChild(specialCont, NULL, (const xmlChar *) "name", name);
    xmlNewChild(specialCont, NULL, (const xmlChar *) "value", value);
    xmlNewChild(specialCont, NULL, (const xmlChar *) "details", details);
}

void deleteNode(xmlNode *node)
{
    xmlUnlinkNode(node);
    xmlFreeNode(node);
}

void printResults()
{
    int i = 0;
    while (cont[i] != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d- %s son of %s son of %s\n", i + 1,
               cont[i]->name, cont[i]->father, cont[i]->grandfather);
        i++;
    }
}

void freeChild(struct child *node)
{
    if (node == NULL) return;
    xmlFree((xmlChar *) node->father);
    xmlFree((xmlChar *) node->grandfather);
    xmlFree((xmlChar *) node->name);
    free(node);
}

void freeChildrenCont(struct child **childrenCont)
{
    int i = 0;
    if (childrenCont == NULL) return;
    while (childrenCont[i] != NULL)
    {
        freeChild(childrenCont[i]);
        i++;
    }
    free(childrenCont);
}

void freeSpouse(struct spouse *node)
{
    if (node == NULL) return;
    if (node->children) freeChildrenCont(node->children);
    xmlFree((xmlChar *) node->husband);
    xmlFree((xmlChar *) node->name);
    free(node);
}

void freeSpousesCont(struct spouse **spousesCont)
{
    int i = 0;
    if (spousesCont == NULL) return;
    while (spousesCont[i] != NULL)
    {
        freeSpouse(spousesCont[i]);
        i++;
    }
    free(spousesCont);
}

void freeSpecial(struct special *item)
{
    if (item == NULL) return;
    xmlFree((xmlChar *) item->name);
    xmlFree((xmlChar *) item->value);
    xmlFree((xmlChar *) item->details);
    free(item);
}

void freeSpecialCont(struct special **specialCont)
{
    int i = 0;
    if (specialCont == NULL) return;
    while (specialCont[i] != NULL)
    {
        freeSpecial(specialCont[i]);
        i++;
    }
    free(specialCont);
}

void freeCont()
{
    freeChildrenCont(cont);
}

void resetCont()
{
    if (cont != NULL)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (cont[i] != NULL)
        {
            freeChild(cont[i]);
            i++;
        }
        memset(cont, 0, MAX * sizeof(struct cont *));
    }
    count = 0;
}

void freeSelected()
{
    if (selected == NULL) return;
    if (selected->father) xmlFree((xmlChar *) selected->father);
    if (selected->grandfather) xmlFree((xmlChar *) selected->grandfather);
    if (selected->name) xmlFree((xmlChar *) selected->name);
    if (selected->spouses) freeSpousesCont(selected->spouses);
    if (selected->specialItems) freeSpecialCont(selected->specialItems);
    if (selected->selectedSpouse) freeSpouse(selected->selectedSpouse);
    if (selected->selectedSpecialItem) freeSpecial(selected->selectedSpecialItem);
    free(selected); 
    selected = NULL;
}

int getOption()
{
    char input[20];
    int n = 0;
    if (fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin)) sscanf(input, "%d", &n);
    return n;
}

void capitalize(char word[])
{
    if (isalpha(word[0])) word[0] = toupper(word[0]);
}

void printSpouses()
{
    int i = 0;
    if (selected)
    {
        printf("Wives:\n");
        if (selected->spouses == NULL) printf("\tnone\n");
        else
        {
            if (selected->spouses[i] == NULL) printf("\tnone\n");
            while (selected->spouses[i] != NULL)
            {
                printf("\t %d. %s\n", i + 1, selected->spouses[i]->name);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}

void printChildren(struct spouse *node)
{
    int i = 0;
    if (selected)
    {
        printf("Children:\n");
        if (node->children == NULL) printf("\tnone\n");
        else
        {
            if (node->children[i] == NULL) printf("\tnone\n");
            while (node->children[i] != NULL)
            {
                printf("\t%d. %s\n", i + 1, node->children[i]->name);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}

void printSpecialItem(struct special *item, int n)
{
    if (n) printf("Item:\n");
    else printf("Item %d:\n", n);
    printf("\tName: %s\n", item->name);
    printf("\tValue: %s\n", item->value);
    printf("\tDetails: %s\n", item->details);
}

void printSpecial()
{
    int i = 0;
    if (selected == NULL) printf("Must select node first\n");
    else if (selected->specialItems == NULL || selected->specialItems[0] == NULL)
        printf("Special:\n\tNo special items found\n");
    else
    {
        printf("special:\n");
        while (selected->specialItems[i] != NULL)
        {
            printSpecialItem(selected->specialItems[i], i + 1);
            i++;
        }
    }
}

void die()
{
    freeSelected();
    freeCont();
    free(cursor);
    xmlFreeDoc(doc);
    xmlCleanupParser();
}

void check(int condition)
{
    if (!condition)
    {
        printf("check failed\n");
        die();
        exit(1);
    }
}

void showInfo()
{
    int i = 0;
    const xmlChar *born, *died, *gender;
    if (selected)
    {
        printf("Name: %s\n", selected->name);
        printf("Father: %s\n", selected->father);
        printf("Grandfather: %s\n", selected->grandfather);
        printf("Born: %s\n", (born = getBirthdate(selected->node)));
        printf("Died: %s\n", (died = getDeathdate(selected->node)));
        printf("Gender: %s\n", (gender = getGender(selected->node)));
        printSpouses();
        if (selected->spouses != NULL && selected->spouses[0] != NULL)
        {
            for (i = 0; selected->spouses[i] != NULL; i++)
            {
                printChildren(selected->spouses[i]);
            }
        }
        else printf("Children:\n\tnone\n");
        xmlFree((xmlChar *) born);
        xmlFree((xmlChar *) died);
        xmlFree((xmlChar *) gender);
    }
    else printf("Must select node first\n");
}

int find(xmlNode *node, const xmlChar *key, const xmlChar *grandfather, const xmlChar *father)
{
    const xmlChar *name;
    xmlNode *cur;

    for (cur = node; cur != NULL && count < MAX; cur = cur->next)
    {
        if (cur->type == XML_ELEMENT_NODE)
        {
            if (!xmlStrcmp(cur->name, (const xmlChar *) "child"))
            {
                name = getName(cur);
                if (!xmlStrcmp(name, key))
                {
                    cont[count] = malloc(sizeof(struct child));
                    cont[count]->grandfather = xmlStrdup(grandfather);
                    cont[count]->father = xmlStrdup(father);
                    cont[count]->name = xmlStrdup(name);
                    cont[count]->node = cur;
                    count++;
                }
                if (cur->children) find(cur->children, key, name, father);
                xmlFree((xmlChar *) name);
            }
            else if (cur->children)
                find(cur->children, key, father, grandfather);
        }
    }
    return (count > 0) ? 1 : 0;
}

void selectNode(struct child *node, const char *type, int option)
{
    xmlNode *cur;
    if (selected == NULL && strcmp(type, "node"))
    {
        printf("Must select a node first\n");
    }
    else if (!strcmp(type, "node"))
    {
        freeSelected();
        selected = calloc(1, sizeof(struct selectedNode)); 
        selected->name = xmlStrdup(node->name);
        selected->father = xmlStrdup(node->father);
        selected->grandfather = xmlStrdup(node->grandfather);
        selected->node = node->node;
        selected->spouses = getSpouses(selected->node, selected->father, selected->grandfather);
        selected->specialItems = getSpecial(selected->node);
        selected->selectedSpouse = NULL;
        selected->selectedSpecialItem = NULL;
        memset(cursor, 0, strlen(cursor));
        strcpy(cursor, (char *) node->name);
        cursor = strcat(cursor, " > ");
    }
    else if (!strcmp(type, "spouse"))
    {
        selected->selectedSpouse = selected->spouses[option];
        memset(cursor, 0, strlen(cursor));
        cursor = (char *) selected->name;
        cursor = strcat(cursor, ":");
        cursor = strcat(cursor, (char *) selected->selectedSpouse->name);
        cursor = strcat(cursor, " > ");
    }
    else if (!strcmp(type, "special"))
    {
        selected->selectedSpecialItem = selected->specialItems[option];
        memset(cursor, 0, strlen(cursor));
        strcpy(cursor, (char *) selected->name);
        cursor = strcat(cursor, "[");
        cursor = strcat(cursor, (char *) selected->selectedSpecialItem->name);
        cursor = strcat(cursor, "] > ");
    }
    else if (!strcmp(type, "child"))
    {
        if (selected->selectedSpouse != NULL)
            selectNode(selected->selectedSpouse->children[option], (const char *) "node", -1);
        else printf("Spouse is not selected\n");
    }
    else if (!strcmp(type, "father"))
    {
        cur = getParent(selected->node);
        check(!xmlStrcmp(getName(cur), selected->father));
        if (cur)
        {
            selected->name = selected->father;
            selected->father = selected->grandfather;
            selected->node = cur;
            selected->spouses = getSpouses(cur, selected->name, selected->father);
            selected->specialItems = getSpecial(cur);
            selected->selectedSpouse = NULL;
            selected->selectedSpecialItem = NULL;
            cur = getParent(cur);
            if (cur) selected->grandfather = getName(cur);
            memset(cursor, 0, strlen(cursor));
            strcpy(cursor, (char *) selected->name);
            cursor = strcat(cursor, " > ");
        }
        else printf("Parent node was not found\n");
    }
    else printf("Unrecognized option %s", (char *) type);
}

void execute(char command[], char value[], char option[])
{
    int rv = 0;
    int n = 0;
    const xmlChar *none = (const xmlChar *) "none";
    if (!strcmp(command, "find"))
    {
        capitalize(value);
        if (value[0] == '\0') printf("Invalid search value\n");
        else if ((rv = find(root, (const xmlChar *) value, none, none)) == 1)
        {
            printf("Found:\n");
            printResults();
            printf("Choose a Person's (number) to select, or (0) to cancel > ");
            if ((n = getOption()) > 0 && n - 1 < MAX && cont[n - 1] != NULL)
            {
                selectNode(cont[n - 1], (const char *) "node", -1);
            }
            resetCont();
        }
        else printf("Nothing found for %s.\n", value);
    }
    else if (!strcmp(command, "info")) showInfo();
    else if (!strcmp(command, "list"))
    {
        if (selected == NULL) printf("Must select a node first\n");
        else
        {
            if (!strcmp(value, "spouses")) printSpouses();
            else if (!strcmp(value, "children"))
            {
                if (selected->selectedSpouse != NULL) printChildren(selected->selectedSpouse);
                else printf("Must select a spouse first\n");
            }
            else if (!strcmp(value, "special")) printSpecial();
            else printf("Invalid command\n");

        }
    }
    else printf("Invalid command\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    LIBXML_TEST_VERSION
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: xml filename.xml\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char input[40];
    char command[40];
    char value[40];
    char option[40];
    cursor = malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(cursor, "> ");
    count = 0;
    cont = calloc(MAX, sizeof(struct child*));
    selected = NULL;

    if ((doc = xmlReadFile(argv[1], NULL, 0)) == NULL)
    {
        printf("error: could not parse file %s\n", argv[1]);
        exit(-1);
    }
    root = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);
    while(1)
    {
        command[0] = '\0';
        value[0] = '\0';
        option[0] = '\0';
        printf("%s", cursor);
        if (fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin)) sscanf(input, "%s %s %s", command, value, option);
        if (!strcmp(command, "exit")) break;

        execute(command, value, option);
    }
    die();
    return 0;
}
```

### valgrind

```
valgrind --leak-check=full --track-origins=yes -v ./xml data.xml
.....(some valgrind initializing output).....
> find luke
--16891-- REDIR: 0x4238b60 (__GI_memchr) redirected to 0x402e7d0 (__GI_memchr)
--16891-- REDIR: 0x42397e0 (__GI_memcpy) redirected to 0x402f090 (__GI_memcpy)
--16891-- REDIR: 0x423b490 (__GI___rawmemchr) redirected to 0x4030ea0 (__GI___rawmemchr)
Found:
1- Luke son of Mike son of John
2- Luke son of John son of none
Choose a Person's (number) to select, or (0) to cancel > 2
--16891-- REDIR: 0x42e8cc0 (__memset_sse2) redirected to 0x4030820 (memset)
Luke > find john
Found:
1- John son of none son of none
Choose a Person's (number) to select, or (0) to cancel > 1
John > find mike
Found:
1- Mike son of John son of none
Choose a Person's (number) to select, or (0) to cancel > 1
==16891== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==16891==    at 0x402B3D8: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==16891==    by 0x80490D7: freeChild (xml.c:286)
==16891==    by 0x8049132: freeChildrenCont (xml.c:298)
==16891==    by 0x804916A: freeSpouse (xml.c:307)
==16891==    by 0x80491C2: freeSpousesCont (xml.c:319)
==16891==    by 0x804939C: freeSelected (xml.c:372)
==16891==    by 0x804A3DB: selectNode (xml.c:544)
==16891==    by 0x804A98F: execute (xml.c:622)
==16891==    by 0x8048BEA: main (xml.c:706)
==16891==  Address 0x440f770 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 5 free'd
==16891==    at 0x402B3D8: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==16891==    by 0x804935F: freeSelected (xml.c:369)
==16891==    by 0x804A3DB: selectNode (xml.c:544)
==16891==    by 0x804A98F: execute (xml.c:622)
==16891==    by 0x8048BEA: main (xml.c:706)
==16891== 
==16891== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==16891==    at 0x402B3D8: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==16891==    by 0x80490E2: freeChild (xml.c:287)
==16891==    by 0x8049132: freeChildrenCont (xml.c:298)
==16891==    by 0x804916A: freeSpouse (xml.c:307)
==16891==    by 0x80491C2: freeSpousesCont (xml.c:319)
==16891==    by 0x804939C: freeSelected (xml.c:372)
==16891==    by 0x804A3DB: selectNode (xml.c:544)
==16891==    by 0x804A98F: execute (xml.c:622)
==16891==    by 0x8048BEA: main (xml.c:706)
==16891==  Address 0x440f7a8 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 5 free'd
==16891==    at 0x402B3D8: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==16891==    by 0x8049374: freeSelected (xml.c:370)
==16891==    by 0x804A3DB: selectNode (xml.c:544)
==16891==    by 0x804A98F: execute (xml.c:622)
==16891==    by 0x8048BEA: main (xml.c:706)
==16891== 
==16891== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==16891==    at 0x402B3D8: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==16891==    by 0x8049175: freeSpouse (xml.c:308)
==16891==    by 0x80491C2: freeSpousesCont (xml.c:319)
==16891==    by 0x804939C: freeSelected (xml.c:372)
==16891==    by 0x804A3DB: selectNode (xml.c:544)
==16891==    by 0x804A98F: execute (xml.c:622)
==16891==    by 0x8048BEA: main (xml.c:706)
==16891==  Address 0x440f770 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 5 free'd
==16891==    at 0x402B3D8: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==16891==    by 0x804935F: freeSelected (xml.c:369)
==16891==    by 0x804A3DB: selectNode (xml.c:544)
==16891==    by 0x804A98F: execute (xml.c:622)
==16891==    by 0x8048BEA: main (xml.c:706)
==16891== 
Mike > exit
==16891== 
==16891== HEAP SUMMARY:
==16891==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==16891==   total heap usage: 566 allocs, 590 frees, 68,257 bytes allocated
==16891== 
==16891== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==16891== 
==16891== ERROR SUMMARY: 24 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==16891== 
==16891== 2 errors in context 1 of 3:
==16891== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==16891==    at 0x402B3D8: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==16891==    by 0x8049175: freeSpouse (xml.c:308)
==16891==    by 0x80491C2: freeSpousesCont (xml.c:319)
==16891==    by 0x804939C: freeSelected (xml.c:372)
==16891==    by 0x804A3DB: selectNode (xml.c:544)
==16891==    by 0x804A98F: execute (xml.c:622)
==16891==    by 0x8048BEA: main (xml.c:706)
==16891==  Address 0x440f770 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 5 free'd
==16891==    at 0x402B3D8: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==16891==    by 0x804935F: freeSelected (xml.c:369)
==16891==    by 0x804A3DB: selectNode (xml.c:544)
==16891==    by 0x804A98F: execute (xml.c:622)
==16891==    by 0x8048BEA: main (xml.c:706)
==16891== 
==16891== 
==16891== 11 errors in context 2 of 3:
==16891== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==16891==    at 0x402B3D8: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==16891==    by 0x80490E2: freeChild (xml.c:287)
==16891==    by 0x8049132: freeChildrenCont (xml.c:298)
==16891==    by 0x804916A: freeSpouse (xml.c:307)
==16891==    by 0x80491C2: freeSpousesCont (xml.c:319)
==16891==    by 0x804939C: freeSelected (xml.c:372)
==16891==    by 0x804A3DB: selectNode (xml.c:544)
==16891==    by 0x804A98F: execute (xml.c:622)
==16891==    by 0x8048BEA: main (xml.c:706)
==16891==  Address 0x440f7a8 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 5 free'd
==16891==    at 0x402B3D8: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==16891==    by 0x8049374: freeSelected (xml.c:370)
==16891==    by 0x804A3DB: selectNode (xml.c:544)
==16891==    by 0x804A98F: execute (xml.c:622)
==16891==    by 0x8048BEA: main (xml.c:706)
==16891== 
==16891== 
==16891== 11 errors in context 3 of 3:
==16891== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==16891==    at 0x402B3D8: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==16891==    by 0x80490D7: freeChild (xml.c:286)
==16891==    by 0x8049132: freeChildrenCont (xml.c:298)
==16891==    by 0x804916A: freeSpouse (xml.c:307)
==16891==    by 0x80491C2: freeSpousesCont (xml.c:319)
==16891==    by 0x804939C: freeSelected (xml.c:372)
==16891==    by 0x804A3DB: selectNode (xml.c:544)
==16891==    by 0x804A98F: execute (xml.c:622)
==16891==    by 0x8048BEA: main (xml.c:706)
==16891==  Address 0x440f770 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 5 free'd
==16891==    at 0x402B3D8: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==16891==    by 0x804935F: freeSelected (xml.c:369)
==16891==    by 0x804A3DB: selectNode (xml.c:544)
==16891==    by 0x804A98F: execute (xml.c:622)
==16891==    by 0x8048BEA: main (xml.c:706)
==16891== 
==16891== ERROR SUMMARY: 24 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: I think I see at least one potential issue within `getChildren`: You do `childrenCont = calloc...` within the outer loop. Won't that mean that on second and following iterations you will lose what you had there previously?

Comment: it wont cause there's only one xml child node "children" within "spouse" node, so basically the inner loop will only execute once if that makes sense

Comment: Actually, this is the outer loop I am talking about, but if it only executes once that isn't what's causing the leak.

Comment: regarding your query about freeing an already free'd area.  That is a no-no as the required heap structure is no longer available (it has already been returned to the overall heap.  However, freeing a null pointer is acceptable as free() checks for that condition.  Suggest always set a pointer to NULL after freeing, so the problem does not arise.

Comment: Can you post `data.xml`, so folks can run this program?

Comment: It wont allow me to add more text to my question, i uploaded it on google drive here [https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-Ec3BudH3zibEM4VnRJa0tFMkU/view?usp=sharing](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-Ec3BudH3zibEM4VnRJa0tFMkU/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Valgrind is telling you, in an example like this:

```
==16891== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==16891==    at 0x402B3D8: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==16891==    by 0x8049175: freeSpouse (xml.c:308)
==16891==    by 0x80491C2: freeSpousesCont (xml.c:319)
==16891==    by 0x804939C: freeSelected (xml.c:372)
==16891==    by 0x804A3DB: selectNode (xml.c:544)
==16891==    by 0x804A98F: execute (xml.c:622)
==16891==    by 0x8048BEA: main (xml.c:706)
==16891==  Address 0x440f770 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 5 free'd
==16891==    at 0x402B3D8: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==16891==    by 0x804935F: freeSelected (xml.c:369)
==16891==    by 0x804A3DB: selectNode (xml.c:544)
==16891==    by 0x804A98F: execute (xml.c:622)
==16891==    by 0x8048BEA: main (xml.c:706)
==16891==
```

is that you're calling `free()` indirectly through `freeSpouse (xml.c:308)` after you've already called `free()` on the same pointer through `freeSelected (xml.c:369)`. The top section tells you about the invalid `free()`, and the bottom section tells you about the original, valid `free()`.

It's showing you three separate error contexts. The original `free()` calls are identified as:

- `freeSelected (xml.c:369)`;
- `freeSelected (xml.c:370)`; and
- `freeSelected (xml.c:369)` again.

which are:

```
if (selected->father) xmlFree((xmlChar *) selected->father);
if (selected->grandfather) xmlFree((xmlChar *) selected->grandfather);
```

The invalid `free()` calls are identified as:

- `freeChild (xml.c:286)`;
- `freeChild (xml.c:287)`; and
- `freeSpouse (xml.c:308)`

which are:

```
xmlFree((xmlChar *) node->father);
xmlFree((xmlChar *) node->grandfather);
xmlFree((xmlChar *) node->husband);
```

What it looks like is happening here is that you are `free()`ing a series of nodes which have reciprocal relationships, and when you, for instance, free `node->father` in `xml.c:286`, it contains a pointer to an `xmlChar *` which you already previously freed in `xml.c:369`.

It's hard to be concrete without having the datafile you're using, and being able to run the program, but in general you essentially have two options in this kind of situation:

1. Wrap *all* your `xmlFree()` calls with a check and `NULL` the pointer after calling it, like so:

   ```
   if ( node->father ) {
       xmlFree((xmlChar *) node->father);
       node->father = NULL;
   }
   ```

   so that the next time you call `xmlFree()` on the same pointer, it'll find that it's `NULL` and skip it.

   The problem is that this is unlikely to work for you, here, if you have two different pointers that point to the same memory. If you set the pointer to `NULL` in one node, it won't set the pointer in the other node to `NULL`, and it will still point to the data which you've freed. That `NULL` check will therefore be checking the wrong pointer, and you'll still get an invalid `free()`. You could get around this by using pointers to pointers, but it'll be messy, and in reality, your best option is likely:
2. Making sure you religiously copy everything (here, probably via `xmlStrdup()`) to make sure you completely avoid that situation of having pointers in different nodes point to the same thing. That way, you can happily free everything and not having to worry about accidentally freeing something twice.

Comment: I changed `temp->husband = husband;` to `temp->husband = xmlStrdup(husband);` in function `*getSpouse()` and `temp->father = father; temp->grandfather = grandfather;` to `temp->father = xmlStrdup(father); temp->grandfather = xmlStrdup(grandfather);` in function `*getChild()` and the errors disappeared :), thanks.

Comment: so as i understand now, the errors were due to the pointers in `selected->name`, `selected->spouses->spouse->husband` and `selected->children->child->father` are the same, likewise in `selected->father` and `selected->children->child->grandfather`, and then getting freed more than once in `freeSelected` right?

Comment: @razzak: Right, due to two different pointers pointing to the same bit of memory.